# Power Automate - how to send an news digest only to members who have not read the news post

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-graph

I'm creating a Power Automate workflow that sends out a news digest to all members of the site. I would like this news digest only to be send to the member(s) when the news post hasn't been read already. How can I build this feature in the workflow?
SharePoint has now an [automatic news digest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugmyd.png) feature that is only send when the news article hasn't been read. It makes use of MS Graph. How can I accomplish this in Power Automate?

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.
Regards, Yannick

Comment: What is problem with using SharePoint default Automatic news digest feature?

Comment: Dear Ganesh, We would like the message to be sent out with a 1 day delay.